# How to Get Proxy Information from PAC file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, networking, proxy

I am using proxy support in my application which works fine for the manual proxy entered into the wifi settings panel but doesn't when we put in the automatic proxy pac file in "Auto" option of the HTTP proxy section for that particular Wifi connection.

The information is not contained within PAC file and hence is dynamic so how do I get my iOS application to consume the pac file for proxy information?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Objective C, you may refer the following snippet for getting proxy details (uses **kCFNetworkProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString**):

```
 CFDictionaryRef dicRef = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();
//Manual Proxy Details
const NSString* proxyStr = (const NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(dicRef, (const void*)kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy);

//Auto Config Proxy Details
NSString* proxyStr2 = ( NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(dicRef, (const void*)kCFNetworkProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString);
// Return something similar to http://someIPAddress:someport/pacfile

if (proxyStr2 != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Proxy %@", proxyStr2);
    // Create an url with the proxy pac
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:proxyStr2];
    if (url != nil)
    {
        NSString* urlPath = [url path];
        // Url path: /pacfile
        NSLog(@"Url %@", urlPath);
        NSError* error;

        // Go fetch the content the url (PAC Content)
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

        if (content == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"StringWithContentsOfUrl Error: %@", error);
        }

        if (content != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"PAC content: %@", content);

            // Parsing of the pac file. This is just a sample parsing script and may change based on what your PAC returns
            NSUInteger firstMatch = [content rangeOfString:@"PROXY "].location + 6;
            NSUInteger secondMatch = [content rangeOfString:@"\"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(firstMatch , [content length] - firstMatch)].location;

            if (firstMatch < 10000 && secondMatch < 10000 && firstMatch > 0 && secondMatch > 0)
            {
               //Just a random label
                self.randLabel3.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"First match and second match: %tu %tu", firstMatch, secondMatch];

            }
        }
    }
}
```